# Is there an example of creating a blob type from string?

Tags: flyte

I need to pass a large string to a workflow - seems that the right way to do it would be using a blob. Will be helpful to have an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From outside a task:

```py
from flytekit.interfaces.data.data_proxy import Data

with open('/tmp/some.file', 'w') as w:
    w.write("Me iz a big string......... x100000000")

Data.put_data('/tmp/some.file', 's3://some/location')

your_launch_plan.execute('project', 'domain', inputs={'string_blob': 's3://some/location'})
```

If you're inside a task, you have a context which allows operating on files in a scratch space, so simply:

```py
my_big_string_blob = Types.Blob()
with my_big_string_blob as w:
    w.write("Me iz a big string......... x100000000")
```

Comment: Thanks. In this example, type of `string_blob` Types.Blob? Also, does Flyte support cleaning up `s3://some/location` after workflow execution is over, or the user needs to take care of that?

Comment: Yes, string_blob should be typed as a Blob in the workflow example. There are ways to override types to have special behavior. So theoretically you could create a StringBlob type which auto-packs and unpacks from a string. But that is a longer discussion.

And no, Flyte does not automatically clean up the s3 object.